# Why won't my simple knockout program work?

Tags: knockout.js

I can do the online tutorials at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro but when I attempt to do the equivalent in HTML page in an empty ASP.NET project it won't work. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AppViewModel() {
            this.firstName = "Bert";
            this.lastName = "Bertington";
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I looked at another link and it works if I move the ko.appyBindings to the bottom:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AppViewModel() {
            this.firstName = "Bert";
            this.lastName = "Bertington";
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Go ahead and move your ko script tag to the bottom as well. You want your scripts to be just before the end of the body tag.

Comment: Ah, right, you tried to apply binding to non existent html. If using jquery you could wrap it with `$(document).ready()` and put whenever you like.